# How do I bring these two elements closer together?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the `#bigimage` and `#textarea` elements to sit closer together, but then still be centered when laid out as `col-12` on a small screen.

Should I use a media query for this? I've tried putting them in a separate container, but strange stuff starts happening when I test that on a small screen.

The colored borders in my attempt below are for my own clarity. I'm just a beginner so if you have any other comments about my code I'd really appreciate it.

```css
header {
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3%;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

h2 {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#textarea {
  border: 3px solid green;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}

#bigimage {
  border: 3px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#mainstuff {
  width: 50% margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#textandphoto {
  width: 800px;
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <header>
        <h1>Raphael Hetherington</h1>
        <h2>11+ Tutor</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="">11+ Tuition</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Programming</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="mainstuff">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6" id="bigimage">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/5/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6" id="textarea">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum omnis harum nesciunt repellendus laudantium quam quo ea, placeat, totam rem laboriosam vero, asperiores architecto. Dolores earum, architecto nemo molestiae quo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus modi eaque placeat voluptates nihil quasi non et similique magnam architecto itaque nobis expedita amet, provident doloribus eveniet quis explicabo?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does eliminating the `margin-top` on `#textarea` work better? Can you clarify what you mean by "closer together"?

Comment: Put them in same column/cell and they will be closer.

Comment: I mean horizontally reduce the padding on the right and left respectively, just by 20px or so.  I don't want to position-relative it because then they won't be centred when the viewport is made smaller...

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I think putting it in the same column is the trick. Massive appreciation

Answer (score 0):

```
#textarea {
      border: 3px solid green;
      text-align: justify;
      margin-top: 0; /* 0 instead of 30px*/
      width: 200px;
 }
```